# How to use useState inside a react functional component which is async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

My `App` is a functional component which is declared `async` because I have to fetch data from the server before view is rendered and the code is as follows

```
import React,{useState} from  "react";
import DashBoard from './components/DashBoard'
const axios = require('axios')


const App = async props => {
  const allDashBoardsList = await axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getAllDashBoardNames')
  const [dashboard,setDashboard] = useState(allDashBoardsList.data[0].dashboard)
  const handleDashboardChange = e => {
    setDashboard(e.target.value)
  }
   return (
    <>
      <select>
        {allDashBoardsList.data.map(e => <option value={e.dashboard} onChange  = {handleDashboardChange} > {e.dashboard} </option>)}
      </select>
      <DashBoard dashboard={dashboard} />
    </>
   )
 }



export default App
```

and my index.js is like this,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
App().then(e => {
    ReactDOM.render(e, document.getElementById('root'));
})
```

Everything works fine without any error when i return just `<h1> Hello </h1>` from `App` but I am getting

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component
```

when I use `useState` to set the state

is there any way to counter this or should I have to use a `class component` with `UNSAFE_componentWillMount`

Comment: You want to use the useEffect hook in your functional component for the async call

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias could you please provide a reference link..this is the first time I am working with hooks.

Comment: No problem. Looks like someone gave an answer below just now. Here's a helpful link: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your async call in the useEffect hook instead and setting an acceptable default state

```
const App = props => {
  const [dashboard,setDashboard] = useState('placeholder default state');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getAllDashBoardNames');
      setDashboard(allDashBoardsList.data[0].dashboard);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleDashboardChange = e => {
    setDashboard(e.target.value)
  }
   return (
    <>
      <select>
        {allDashBoardsList.data.map(e => <option value={e.dashboard} onChange  = {handleDashboardChange} > {e.dashboard} </option>)}
      </select>
      <DashBoard dashboard={dashboard} />
    </>
   )
 }
```